# "Ho perso la verginità con un ragazzo che detesto per quanto ci è successo dopo": significato di "per quanto ci"

Tags: meaning, grammar

> Ho perso la verginità con un ragazzo che detesto per quanto ci è successo dopo.

Cosa vuol dire "per quanto ci" in questa frase?

Comment: Ciao, Damian! Secondo me, la tua domanda migliorerebbe molto se cercassi di consultare un dizionario e ci spiegassi cosa non hai capito o quali difficoltà hai avuto (per esempio, a volte cerchi una parola sul dizionario e ci sono tante accezioni che non riesci a vedere a quale corrisponda l'uso che ha generato il tuo dubbio o le definizioni sono troppo difficili da capire...).

Comment: Tuttavia, devo dire che mi sembra una domanda interessante.

Answer (score 2):

Probabilmente l'origine del problema è *per quanto*. In questo caso è un complemento di causa: *a causa di quanto ci è successo dopo*. In altri contesti *per quanto* può essere una congiunzione concessiva (ma in questo caso richiede il congiuntivo).

Dal [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quanto1)

> **4.** […] **b.** Preceduto dalle prep. *da* o *per*, con lo stesso uso e sign. avverbiale di tanto: *quest’acqua non si può bere, da (o per) q. è gelata.* **c.** Preceduto da *per*, nella locuz. di valore concessivo *per quanto* (con il verbo al cong.): *per q. si sforzi, non ci riuscirà mai*; *il problema, per q. sia difficile, si può risolvere*; usata assol., all’inizio di frase, serve a sospendere e correggere quanto s’è appena affermato: *gli scriverò ... per quanto ... sarà forse meglio dirglielo a voce.*

L'ultimo esempio può essere fuorviante perché c'è l'indicativo: ma è futuro e c'è appunto *forse* per rafforzare il significato di opinione.

Nel caso in esame *per quanto* non è una locuzione: si può sostituire *quanto* con *quello che* e il significato non cambierebbe.

Quindi si potrebbe volgere in

> che (ora) detesto a causa di quello che ci è successo dopo

e *ci* è semplicemente un pronome di seconda persona plurale: *quello che è successo a noi dopo*.

Comment: Minuscola correzione: si può sostituire “quanto” con “quello che”.

Comment: @DaG Grazie, in effetti mancava